# Simplify getting the data from the form

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, httpcontext

I filled out the form, and received data on the server like this:

```
model.Firstname = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Firstname"];
model.Lastname = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Lastname"];
model.Middlename = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Middlename"];
model.Avatar = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Avatar"];
model.Birthday = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Birthday"];
```

Model:

```
public int CustomerID { get; set; }
public int StatusID { get; set; }
public string Firstname { get; set; }
public string Lastname{ get; set; }
public string Middlename { get; set; }
public string Birthday { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to make it easier and combine this lines?

Comment: This is actually really good I suggest keeping it like this.

Comment: Sure, I think that's ok when you use not many fields, but in this case I've got a more fields

Comment: yes this is possible what can you give  us more info about your _model_ ?

Comment: Oh sure, I added changes

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET WebForms or MVC?

Comment: In this case I use MVC

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an extension method and use reflection to set your properties, like this:

```
public static void SetProperties<T>(this T source, HttpContext context)
{
     var properties = typeof(T)
             .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

     var  values = context.Request.QueryString;

     foreach (var prop in properties)
     {
         if (values.AllKeys.Contains(prop.Name))
         {
             prop.SetValue(source,values[prop.Name]);
         }
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
mode.SetProperties(HttpContext.Current);
```

This assumes that your keys in the query string  are exactly matches with your property names of the `model`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net mvc, you don't have to specifically assign each property through the HttpContext, you can directly send the serialized data of your form and receive as strongly typed model object in your function, something like :

```
[HttpPost]
public TMServiceResponse Customer_Save(CustomerModel obj)
{
     //make your form actionmethod like this
}
```

and post it from the view like this:

```
var form = jQuery("#myformId");
jQuery(".btnCustomerSubmit").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var result = form.valid();
    if (result === true) {
        var url = '/ControllerName/Customer_Save';
        var data = form.serialize();
        //send post request using jQuery Ajax
        $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: "post",
           data: data,
           success:function(msg){}
        });
    }
});
```

where `.btnCustomerSubmit` represents the submit button of your form, just that, it is usual button, with a click handler and post request is sent explicitly

Comment: Yes, it also a good idea, but in my case all parametrs are passed as a QueryString parametrs

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Automapper](http://automapper.org/). AFAIK it doesn't have Dictionary to Object mapping out-of-the-box, but here i found an example how to do that with few custom code:

http://automapper.codeplex.com/workitem/3266

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
var queryString = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;
var model = new Model 
{
    Firstname = queryString["Firstname"],
    Lastname = queryString["Lastname"],
    Middlename = queryString["Middlename"],
    Avatar = queryString["Avatar"],
    Birthday = queryString["Birthday"]
};
```

This is faster than reflection and more reliable. It won't start failing (or silently skip items) if someone renames **Model.Firstname** to **Model.FirstName**.